# C# How to iterate through nullable list?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am interfacing to an API that exposes the following function:

```
IEnumerable<Color?> getColors(long Id);
```

I call the function:

```
IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Color?> colList = getColors(1);
```

The list is not null when the function returns. However, when I attempt to iterate through the list:

```
foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList)
{...}
```

I get nothing. The loop is not entered.

What is the correct way to iterate through the list?

**Edit**: I finally figured out how to get a list count with this bit of voodoo:

```
int colCount = colList.Count<System.Drawing.Color?>();
```

The count is indeed zero, as has been suggested. I'm now off to the provider of the API to ask why so?

Thank you to all who provided positive and constructive suggestions.

Comment: There's something else going on here, I'm afraid. [Iterating a list of nullable works](https://rextester.com/GIL80455).

Comment: You should check the Count() it sounds like the collection is empty

Comment: Just a thought, but you are assuming that the list wont have nullable values in your foreach, perhaps you should use the nullable form instead of casting it to Color

Comment: it sounds like it is non-null but empty; that's... pretty normal; do you have a reason to think that the sequence is (or should be) non-empty?

Comment: Remember that `IEnumerable` is basically a view. If it's a one time thing you could be exhausting it by inspecting the results with the debugger.

Comment: If the loop is not entered, the collection is probably empty. Empty and null are different things. Also, if the elements are `Color?`, then that's what's the loop variable should be, not `Color`.

Comment: That `foreach` statement will fail with an `InvalidOperationException` if a `NULL` value is encountered. However, what do you mean with "The loop is not entered"? Maybe your `IEnumerable` is empty?

Comment: @MongZhu When I type a period after `colList`, the Intellisense list incudes `Count`. However, when I compile `colList.Count` or `colList.Count()`, I get `error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Color?>' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Color?>' could be found `

Comment: @mjwills I tried `foreach (var col in colList)` and the loop still does not execute.

Comment: @MarcGravell The list is empty for all records retrieved from the database. I know for sure that some of the records have colors associated with them, and the list should not be empty in many cases. The API was modified recently, and used to return a non-empty list of colors.

Comment: `loop still does not execute.` Then it is 100% empty.

Answer (score 5):

The iterator is empty. That is why it does not enter the loop.

---

However, please note that you do not have a nullable type in your loop:

```
IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Color?> colList = getColors(1);
// System.Drawing.Color is not nullable:
foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(col);
}
```

Which will result in an `InvalidOperationException` when a null comes (because it cannot cast `null` to `System.Drawing.Color`). Use a `System.Drawing.Color?` (or use `var`) instead.

Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var col in getColors(1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(col == null);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}


static IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Color?> getColors(long Id)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

*Outputs True*

---

About using the extension method [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8), know that it might be iterating over the `IEnumerable<Color?>`※. In that case, I would suggest to use [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8) and check the size of the array. With that said, know that a `IEnumerable<Color?>` could also be infinite.

※: As per the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1314), `Count` could be casting to `ICollection<TSource>` or `ICollection` to get the `Count` property from there. Otherwise it will iterate.

Trivial example of infinite `IEnumerable<Color?>`:

```
static IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Color?> getColors(long Id)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

If you need to handle the empty case, another option is to set a variable inside the loop. If the variable is set, you know it is not empty.

Example:

```
bool isEmpty = true;
foreach (var col in getColors(1))
{
    isEmpty = false;
    // ...
}

if (isEmpty)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

*As [Dmitry Bychenko points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56527989/402022), you might be interested in [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8).*

---

**Addendum**:

The [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface has *only* a [`GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) method. However, C# supports [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), and you will find a large number of extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.8), including `Count`, `ToArray` and `OfType`.

To use these extension methods add `using System.Linq;` to your code file. Example:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

static void Main()
{
    var colors = getColors(1).ToArray();
    // ...
}
```

Or call them as regular methods. Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var colors = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(getColors(1));
    // ...
}
```

These last two code examples are equivalent. Usually the former is prefered.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, `Color?` is *nullable*, when `Color` is *not*. If you want to get only *not null* values (`Color`), you can add *Linq* `OfType<T>()`:

```
 using System.Linq; // OfType<T>() is declared as Linq extension method

 ... 

 // loop over not null cols only
 foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>()) {
   ...
 }
```

**Demo:**

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<System.Drawing.Color?> list = new List<System.Drawing.Color?>() {
    System.Drawing.Color.Red,
    System.Drawing.Color.Black,
    null,                        // <- should be excluded
    System.Drawing.Color.Blue,
  };

  foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in list.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>())
    Console.WriteLine(col);
```

**Outcome:**

```
   Color [Red]
   Color [Black]
   Color [Blue]
```

Comment: I personally like the idea of `.OfType()`, but this is **not** what the user is asking for.

Comment: @n0idea Thanks for the prompt and prolific response! When I try `foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>())` I get: `error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Color?>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no accessible extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Color?>' could be found`. Also there does not seem to be a `count` method.

Comment: @Pierre: please, add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @Pierre It does happen when the null is reached. You should consider either `foreach (Color? col in colList)` and handle the nulls or `foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>())` and adding [the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OfType__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the feedback. I have added `using System.Linq`, and tried all the following combinations, none of which iterate through the list: `foreach (var col in colList)`, `foreach (var col in colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>())`, `foreach (System.Drawing.Color col in colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color>())`, `foreach (System.Drawing.Color? col in colList)`. The following results in a compilation error: `foreach (Color? col in colList)`. My biggest problem is that `colList.Count()` does not compile.

Comment: @Pierre: The right syntax for `Count` is  `colList.OfType<System.Drawing.Color?>().Count()` - we turn collection into `IEnumerable<T>` and then call *Linq* `Count()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not in relation to the nullable values of the IEnumerable. If you run this code (https://rextester.com/):

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add(null);
list.Add("asd1");
list.Add(null);
list.Add("asd2");
list.Add(null);
IEnumerable<String> enumerable = list.AsEnumerable();
foreach(var item in enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine('"' + item + '"');
}
```

The output will be:

```
""
"asd1"
""
"asd2"
""
```

So as you can see the null values are not removed from the IEnumerable and we still iterate through the empty values. More than likely the IEnumerable is empty.

Comment: None of the comments is associating the type used in the `foreach` statement to the problem the user is facing, but it is a problem that still needs to be fixed. However, your code isn't failing because of the use of `var` instead of the explicit type which instead would cause a `InvalidOperationException` in case of a `NULL` value.

Comment: @n0idea The OP said "The loop is not entered." so i thought the user assumed that null values were being removed. Also String is a nullable type so this example works with `var` and `String` inside the loop. Color is a struct and so not nullable.